# Setting request headers in Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, http-proxy, jupyter

I have been working with node.js to set up a proxy server that will handle incoming client request and will verify that they have the proper certificates to get connected to the server.

What I want to do is to be able to add the client's certificate to their header to craft a user name, that I will pass on to the server.

```
function (req, res) {

//Here is the client certificate in a variable 
var clientCertificate = req.socket.getPeerCertificate();

// Proxy a web request
return this.handle_proxy('web', req, res);

};
```

What I want to be able to do is this : `req.setHeader('foo','foo')`

I know that the  `proxy.on('proxyReq)` exist, but the way the code is set up, I need to be able to use the `req` parameter.

Is there a way to do this?

Please let me know if I need to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft your own http request with the headers provided in the original request plus any extra headers that you'd like by using [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). Just receive the original request, copy the headers into the new request headers, add the new headers and send the new request.

```
var data = [];
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data.push(chunk);
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(data.join(""));

    //send the response to your original request

  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// Set headers here i.e. req.setHeader('Content-Type', originalReq.getHeader('Content-Type'));

// write data to request body

req.write(/*original request data goes here*/);
req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you explain a little more on how you are copying the header into a new request header? Im just still a little confused how you are doing that in the above code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the spot for setting the headers, you would do it before you call write, I'll update the location in the code.

Comment: A few more questions: what are in the options that you are passing to the request? Why can this be done on the proxy?

Comment: This is the proxy. I added the options from the http.request sample code to clarify. You can add the headers in the options or anytime before calling "write". If I need custom headers, I normally add them outside of the options so that I can reuse the crafted http.request, but it's your choice where to put them.

Comment: So I want to make the headers be the the client certificate, which I do by req.socket.getPeerCertificate. How could I add that to the header?

Comment: I would try req.setHeader("Auth", req.socket.getPeerCertificate())

Comment: Should I include that in the above code? Or should I be able to execute that req.setHeader without it?

Comment: Hey one more question, what do you mean by "/*original request data goes here*/", what is the original request?

Comment: The original request is the one that the client made, in the code I provided "req" refers to the new request you're crafting and "originalRequest" is the one that came from the client. Since you're building a proxy, you need to forward the request body, i.e. if you POSTed {"id":1} from the client, you need to put {"id":1} as the param for req.write so that it gets forwarded to the proxied location.